# WatiN FindByIdStartsWith?

Tags: watin

How to find element by start of id in WatiN?

```
Find.ById(x => x.StartsWith(rel)
```

Didn't work somehow. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to check whether `x` has a value before calling `StartsWith()`

```
Find.ById(x => x != null && x.StartsWith(rel));
```

Comment: Found this too, but somehow got problems. Maybe that was my own fault. Focusing on other problems at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

RegEx pwnage =>

```
 var regex = new Regex(rel + ".*");
 var links = Browser.ElementsOfType<Link>()
     .Filter(Find.By("rel", regex));
```